# ADB Bash script drops connection before finishing

Tags: shell

So I have a bunch of android units I'm installing APKs on and sending config files to it and this works perfectly on a batch script but when I tried to write it on the shell for Linux it drops connection half the time and says no device.

```
while read ip1; do
    echo $ip1
    echo Entered: $ip1
    adb </dev/null connect $ip1
    adb devices
    adb </dev/null root
    adb </dev/null remount
    adb </dev/null uninstall com.neldtv.mips
    adb </dev/null uninstall com.gate.mips
    adb </dev/null install MIPS_DS_Basic_GATE_V1.7.0.4.2.0.apk
    echo Transfering settings file now!
    adb </dev/null push shared_data.xml /data/data/com.gate.mips/shared_prefs/shared_data.xml
    adb </dev/null shell su -c "chmod 777 -R /data/data/com.gate.mips/shared_prefs"
    adb </dev/null shell setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/New_York"
    adb </dev/null push build.prop /system/build.prop
    adb </dev/null shell su -c "chmod 644 /system/build.prop"
    adb </dev/null disconnect $ip1
done <input.txt
```

I had to redirect the stdin for Linux to dev/null so my loop doesn't end after one iteration. I'm not sure if this has something to do with it but for whatever reason, after it gets to adb root line it disconnects from the device and says "waiting for device" so when I Ctrl-C out the script and run 'adb devices' it shows no connected devices. Adding/removing -s $ip1 in front of the commands does nothing either. The device is just disconnected right after it gets connected so I'm not sure what's causing that. Did anyone get any ideas?

Comment: To stop needing all the `</dev/null`s, consider making it `done 3<input.txt` and `while read ip1 <&3; do` -- that way you don't have to worry about adb consuming stdin.

Comment: (`while IFS= read- r ip1` would be better practice, and likewise changing all the uses of bare `$ip1` to `"$ip1"`, but if it really is just simple IP address values and `IFS` hasn't been overwritten to include numbers or dots, none of those issues are likely to be impacting you right now; still, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and reading the wiki links in the warnings it generates to understand what _could_ go wrong following these practices in other scenarios).

Comment: Wow. this was horrible to read. Please learn to use quotes when it's needed. See below example vs yours, this is just one way of many ways to write your script better when asking for help since your script is not easy to read tbh: #!/bin/bash adb="$(/usr/bin/adb </dev/null)"; $adb 'root'; $adb 'remount'; $adb 'su -c "foocommand2"' Sorry for OT but really wanted to say this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. For some reason when I use adb from just installing it with apt get it would do that but downloading the platform-tool zip and putting in the same folder as my script and running ./adb instead of just adb fixed the issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If you using the binary from apt and trying execute it as '/usr/bin/adb ...' will it result in same issue? *If* problem still exist, is the version from zip and apt same version of adb? If problem still exist, try run both way with -x flag enable and please share the difference of output when it exiting with apt version, just curios what causing this :)